# Handle event bubbling in jquery

Tags: jquery, event-bubbling

I have a simple HTML table looking something like this

```
 <table id='resultGrid'>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <a href='javascript:callAction(xxx)'>Johnny</a>
      </td>
      <td>
         Active
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
        <a href='javascript:callAction(yyy)'>Nitro</a>
      </td>
      <td>
         In Active
      </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

and i wanted to handle both row clik and hypherlink click. Since the hepher link is already attached to callAction() function, i used jquery to add click event to the row

```
$("#resultGrid tr").each(function(){
        $(this).css('cursor','hand');
        $(this).click(function() {
             //My logic
        });
});
```

Now problem is everytime i click the hyperlink, the row click event also fires. How can i prevent this.

Comment: Because the hyperlink is inside the tablerow, and the tablerows callback will trigger first as it's the parent element of the anchor.

Comment: @Ziga, i understand that... whats the way to avoid this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `e.target.nodeName`

```
$("#resultGrid tr").each(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor', 'hand');
    $(this).click(function(e) {
        alert(e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'a');
    });
});
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/bEDNB/)

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent event bubling by using

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

Also you can use CSS to assign styles for your `tr` elements.

```
$("#resultGrid a").click(function(e){
    // do your code
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent event bubbling
});
```